# How to split binary file based on pattern?

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to split a binary file into smaller files based on pattern 'xÚ' (it's 78 DA in hexadecimal), so when there's an 'xÚ' in the file the splitter script splits and pastes the content into a new file until another 'xÚ' can be found. The newly created files should start as 'xÚ'.

FreeBSD `awk`, `grep`, `sh` preferred.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Ok here is the cleanup of that mess:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS=/\x78\xda/ } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i > i }' YOUR_BIN_FILE
```

Empty RS could still be causing unexpected results as it makes awk seperate records at blank lines. In fact it is difficult to circumvent a splitup of a file into records. One way to solve this is to set the record seperator to some pattern that is not present in the file. Another way would be to seperate records by 78da and process every record.

Comment: You could `echo "78da$i" | xxd ...`. You don't need `cat`: `xxd -ps -c $FILESIZE $MY_BINARY`. You may need to set `RS` to null in awk to keep it from splitting on `\x0a`: `BEGIN {RS=""}`. You can make it easier to reassemble the files if you use `printf` to format the filenames: `outfile=$(printf "outfile.%04d" $COUNT)` (filenames will look like "outfile.0001"). You don't need redirection for output from `xxd -r`: `xxd -r -ps -c $FILESIZE - $outfile`.

Comment: I like my cat ;) I needed the hint to empty RS, thanks! I removed the mess that caused eyes bleeding.